# How to return custom Error Response when item not found

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, mutiny

Trying to send custom error message when item not found. `ifNotNull` case correct generate required response. But `ifNull` not generate required response (Always the response is empty with status code 200)

AuthorService.java

```
public Uni<Author> findByName(String name) {
    return authorRepo.findByName(name);
}
```

Resource.java

```
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
public Uni<Response> get(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return authorService.findByName(name)
            .onItem().ifNotNull().transform(t -> new ResponseBodyDTO("success", true, t))
            .onItem().transform(t -> Response.ok(t).build())
            .onItem().ifNull().switchTo(() -> Uni.createFrom().item(new ResponseBodyDTO("fail", false, null))
                    .onItem().transform(t -> Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(t).build()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
public Uni<Response> get(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return authorService.findByName(name)
            .onItem().ifNotNull().transform(t -> Response.ok(new ResponseBodyDTO("success", true, t)).build())
            .onItem().ifNull().continueWith(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(new ResponseBodyDTO("fail", false, null)).build())
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to send Uni<CustomObj> with a http code as 400?

Comment: Yes, you need to `Response.status(400).entity(...).build()` instea of the `Response.ok(...)` code in the answers.